# HashMap Alternative for Storing Integers

Tags: java, data-structures, hash, hashmap

I have a small set of integers (large range). I need to be able to query this data structure at 0(1) and say whether or not an integer exists in the collection. I am currently using Java & Colt OpenIntIntHashMap.
I have a lot of these OpenIntIntHashMaps data structures, and each contain between 5-15 integers. I query in high volume. I just care for the existence of an integer - I do not care about storing a value for the key. Is there another representation or something faster to help solve this problem?

Comment: @iLate: The amortized behaviour is O(1), though (I think).

Comment: @Annonymous: hashmaps have poor locality of reference.  For small sets of only 5 integers you'll probably be faster with linear search inside an *int[]* on quite some CPUs.

Comment: @NoozNooz42 I also think the O(1) requirement is a bit daft for a large number of structures that only contain 5..15 32 bit integers. Who needs O(1) if an iteration would take a microsecond, if not less? I don't see any hash taking less time than a simple lookup.

Comment: O(1) can't occur, in general, because any sort of indexing slows down as the size being indexed increases.  It just so happens that with a small hashtable in RAM indexing even with one entry has already been slowed down to the the speed needed to address a few million, but go one over the indexing ability of the RAM and you'll fall off a cliff.   ALL addressing/indexing is ultimately O(log N) (or worse).

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid I'm not an expert, but I think it will be difficult to achieve true O(1) lookup. However, you might want to look at some sort of perfect hashing. If these sets are small then you may have the opportunity to generate a 'perfect' hash function for them - i.e. it would have no collisions among the items in the set. This should then allow you O(1) lookup - you take your integer, hash it, the hash takes you to exactly one place, and then you do exactly one comparison to check if the integer is inside the set or out. You only need to check once because unlike with an imperfect hash, there are no collisions (between anything in the set, things inside and out may collide), so you only need to check one cell in the table to see if an integer is in the set. This should be O(1) lookup, but the cost of computing such a hash function may be high, and the hash function itself may be much more expensive than general purpose hash functions (although still O(1)). I have no experience using these in Java at all, but JPerf seems to have methods to generate them for any kind of Java objects, which I imagine you might be able to modify to specialise to primitive ints (JPerf is GPLv2).

http://www.anarres.org/projects/jperf/

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function#Minimal_perfect_hashing

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow, looking forward to seeing more of these kind of answers! Do you know if jperf would be a viable option for something that is basically a set instead of a map? The first page requires the input of a map...

Comment: It would need some adaptation, but the basic structure of both is usually the same - you have some key to look up, which may be present. The difference is that in a map you also have a value stored with the key. So, if you need to use a map as a set, you could just have different keys present or not present in the map, and just use whatever object as the value (could even be the same object for all keys so you don't even have to spend time allocating a new object). I had assumed he would want to modify and specialise the collection himself anyway to use ints instead of Integer objects.

Comment: Also, thank you for the welcome. Just to add, as @erickson mentioned, achieving O(1) lookup may not actually give you the fastest performance for small sets.

Answer (score 2):

with 10 numbers, hash set and tree set perform about the same - about 10^7 on my old machine.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main {
    int n = 10;
    Random random = new Random();
    Set<Integer> hashSet = new HashSet<Integer>(n);
    Set<Integer> treeSet = new HashSet<Integer>(n);
    {
        List<Integer> numbers = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            numbers.add(random.nextInt());
        System.out.println(numbers);
        hashSet.addAll(numbers);
        treeSet.addAll(numbers);
        System.out.println(numbers);
    }
    int hits, misses;
    void init() {

    }
    long time(Set<Integer> set, int n) {
        long t0 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            if (set.contains(random.nextInt())) hits++;
            else
                misses++;
        return System.currentTimeMillis() - t0;
    }
    void print(long dt, int n, String set) {
        System.out.println(set + " " + n + " trials in " + dt + " ms. = " + 1000. * n / dt + "trials/sec.");
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int trials = 10000000;
        long dt=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Main main = new Main();
            dt = main.time(main.hashSet, trials);
            main.print(dt, trials, "hashSet");
            dt = main.time(main.treeSet, trials);
            main.print(dt, trials, "treeSet");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

With such a small "n", I wouldn't base a decision on the complexity of the structure; I'd profile and see what is actually fastest.

An Ο(log(n)) algorithm can be faster than an Ο(1) algorithm up to a certain value of n. The Ο notation just tells you how the algorithm scales. In fact, if you have a lot of these maps, you might worry more about space efficiency.

Comment: A good point well put. I imagine that for these small sets, a basic binary tree may be faster, especially if you build it from an array so it's easily balanced if modifications after creation are not needed.